# Verifying eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How would you check whether eigenvalues $\lambda_1=8$, $\lambda_2=3$, $\lambda_3=-1$ belong to a matrix? $$
        \begin{matrix}
        7 & 1 & 1\\
        3 & 1 & 2 \\
        1 & 3 & 2 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

Comment: Is there something wrong with calculating $\text{det}(A-\lambda_i I)$ for each eigenvalue?

Comment: Subtract from the diagonal and check if the new matrix is singular?

Comment: @JimmyK4542 seems like that would take a long time, and the question only asks to verify

Comment: @900sit-upsaday I'll give that a shot

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense. Cheers guys

Answer (score 10):

One method would be to simply check that $\text{det}(A-\lambda_i I) = 0$ for each of the three eigenvalues.

Another method would be to check the following conditions:

$\text{tr}(A) = \lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3$

$\text{det}(A) = \lambda_1\lambda_2\lambda_3$

$\text{tr}(A^2) = \lambda_1^2+\lambda_2^2+\lambda_3^2$

If you know the values of $\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3$, and $\lambda_1\lambda_2\lambda_3$, and $\lambda_1^2+\lambda_2^2+\lambda_3^2$, then this uniquely determines the values of $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$, $\lambda_3$ up to a permutation.

Answer (score 3):

they must make this determinant zero :
$$\left | A-\lambda I \right |=\begin{vmatrix}
7- \lambda&  1&1 \\ 
 3& 1 -\lambda& 2\\ 
1 &3  & 2-\lambda
\end{vmatrix}$$